# How to refer to a multiple similar hstore key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I have OpenStreetMap data loaded to a PostgreSQL database. A hstore type column contains all of the key=value pairs. Some OSM keys have suffixes like `name:en, name:de, name:hu` etc..

I would like to create a query where I can refer to all the `name` keys, the simple `name` and the suffixed `name:en, name.de` ... as well.
I would like to see if there is any record where the value to any of the `name` keys equal to `'some string'`.

The absolutely not stylish and memory friendly workaround I came up with:

Select all the unique name keys:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT DISTINCT(skeys(tags)) as key FROM public.ways)
SELECT key FROM a WHERE key~'^name$' OR key~'^name:';
```

In a text editor create a query like this:

```
WITH string(s1) AS (VALUES('some string'))
SELECT * FROM public.ways,string WHERE tags->'name' ~ s1 
UNION SELECT * FROM public.ways,string WHERE tags->'name:en' ~ s1 
UNION SELECT * FROM public.ways,string WHERE tags->'name:de' ~ s1;
```

Answer (score 5):

While I was writing the question I came up with a better solution:

```
SELECT * FROM public.ways WHERE tags::text~'"name"=>".*"' AND tags::text~'"name:.*"=>".*"'
```

- tags::text~'"name"=>".*"' will find every key value pair where the `name` key has a value
- tags::text~'"name:.*"=>".*"' will find every key value pair where the `name` key with suffixes (like `name:en`,`name:de`) has a value